# When form send adds \r\n to the code i put inside

Tags: php, forms, ads

Here is the full page code

```
<?php
if (!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION['admin_vmp']))
    header('Location: ./login.php');
    include "header.php";
    include "../functions.php";
if(isset($_POST['leaderboard1']))
{
    $leaderboard1 = $_POST["leaderboard1"];
    $leaderboard1=mysql_real_escape_string($leaderboard1);

    $leaderboard2 = $_POST["leaderboard2"];
    $leaderboard2=mysql_real_escape_string($leaderboard2);

    $medrec = $_POST["medrec"];
    $medrec=mysql_real_escape_string($medrec);

    update_ads($leaderboard1,$leaderboard2,$medrec);
}
?>
    <title>Ads - <?php echo(get_title()) ?></title>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    $(window).load(function(){
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#selectall').click(function () {
            $('.selectedId').prop('checked', this.checked);
        });

        $('.selectedId').change(function () {
            var check = ($('.selectedId').filter(":checked").length == $('.selectedId').length);
            $('#selectall').prop("checked", check);
        });
    });
    }); 
    </script>
    <?php
    include "header_under.php";
    ?>      
        <div id="containerHolder">
            <div id="container">
                <div id="sidebar">
                    <ul class="sideNav">
                        <li><a href="./settings.php">Website</a></li>
                        <li><a href="./thumbnails.php">Thumbnails</a></li>
                        <li><a href="./watermark.php">Watermark</a></li>
                        <li><a href="./media.php">Media</a></li>
                        <li><a href="./social.php">Social Media</a></li>
                        <li><a href="./ads.php" class="active">Ad Management</a></li>
                        <li><a href="./admin.php">Admin Settings</a></li>
                        <li><a href="./analytics.php">Analytics (Stats Tracking)</a></li>
                        <li><a href="./rss.php">RSS Settings</a></li>
                        <li><a href="./sitemap.php">Sitemap Settings</a></li>
                        <li><a href="./comments.php">Comments Setting</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- // .sideNav -->
                </div>    
                <!-- // #sidebar -->

                <!-- h2 stays for breadcrumbs -->
                <h2>Ad Management</h2>

                <div id="main">
                    <br />
                    <form action="./ads.php" method="post">
                        <fieldset>
                        <p><a name="top_leaderboard"><label><b>Top : Large leaderboard (728 x 90)</b></label></a><textarea name="leaderboard1"><?php echo(show_leaderboard1_ad()) ?></textarea></p>
                        <p><a name="bottom_leaderboard"><label><b>Bottom : Large leaderboard (728 x 90)</b></label></a><textarea name="leaderboard2"><?php echo(show_leaderboard2_ad()) ?></textarea></p>
                        <p><label><a name="med_rec"><b>Sidebar : Medium Rectangle (300 x 250)</b></label></a><textarea name="medrec"><?php echo(show_rectangle_ad()) ?></textarea></p>
                        <input type="submit" class="myButton" value="Update Ads">
                        </fieldset>
                    </form>
                        <?php
                        if(isset($_POST['leaderboard1']))
                        echo('<div class="alert alert-success">Ads Updated Successfully</div>');
                        ?>
                </div>
                <!-- // #main -->

                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
            <!-- // #container -->
        </div>  
        <!-- // #containerHolder -->
<?php
include "footer.php";
?>
```

Im using this for google ads, after adding the ad code its saves but automaticly ads \r\n in some places.. Is there posibble way to fix this.

Wat i want to fix.. I want to fix that \r\n not to be putted after saving the code so if i put ads will be clean and same as google gives them.

Thank you very much!

```
function update_ads($leaderboard1,$leaderboard2,$medrec)
{

    $update_query = "UPDATE ads SET leaderboard1='".mysql_real_escape_string($leaderboard1)."',leaderboard2='".mysql_real_escape_string($leaderboard2)."',rectangle='".mysql_real_escape_string($medrec)."'";
    mysql_query($update_query);
}
```

Comment: i read it twice, and have no idea what you are asking

Comment: @Dagon when i put my ad code in the form and save it, automaticly adds
"\r\n" in few places..

Comment: show us the `update_ads` function

Comment: You are using `mysql_real_escape_string()`. Are you saving things to a database? You're going to need to post your `update_ads()` function to be sure, but I think you are escaping things for database and then using them for non-database purposes.

Comment: @Dagon update in first post

Comment: you are running mysql_real_escape_string twice, thats why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are running `mysql_real_escape_string` twice (inside the function and before you parse the values to the function), that's the problem

change

```
$leaderboard1 = $_POST["leaderboard1"];
$leaderboard1=mysql_real_escape_string($leaderboard1);

$leaderboard2 = $_POST["leaderboard2"];
$leaderboard2=mysql_real_escape_string($leaderboard2);

$medrec = $_POST["medrec"];
$medrec=mysql_real_escape_string($medrec);

update_ads($leaderboard1,$leaderboard2,$medrec);
```

to

```
update_ads($_POST["leaderboard1"],$_POST["leaderboard2"],$_POST["medrec"]);
```

Comment: so how to fix it? im kind newbie to this things

Comment: if doing something twice is wrong, and once is right, remove one of the times you do whatever it is

Comment: Thats the problem im getting confused on that part.. What shoud i remove :D and where :D sorry for beeing noob..